# Material ui slider with buffer in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an audio player in which users can seek a specific time.I want to show the buffered progress in slider element. There is a linear progress element in material-ui that  shows buffer,but it doesn't have the seek property.How can I achieve both the seek and buffered progress functions?

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for the same thing. I do not believe Material UI's slider component currently provides this ability.